# Write a for loop to subset a dataframe based on matches with a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I want to create new dataframes for each unique `gs_name` in the list of dataframe `lst`. Then, I want to subset `all.deg` to keep rows only if the `rownames(all.deg)` match `gs_name`.

```
for (i in lst){                                                      # For each dataframe in list
  i$gs_name = gsub(".*?_", "", i$gs_name)                            # remove everything before first underscore
  for (j in unique(i$gs_name)){                                      # for each unique `gs_name`
    df <- split(i, j)                                                # create a new dataframe
    paste0(names(lst), j) <- all.deg[rownames(all.deg) %in% df$gene_symbol,]  # retrieve the subset of `all.deg` based on matches to the df
  }
}
```

Traceback:

```
Error in paste0(names(lst), j) <- all.deg[rownames(all.deg) %in% df$gene_symbol,  : 
  could not find function "paste0<-"
```

Input:

```
> dput(lst)
list(Hallmark = structure(list(gs_name = c("HALLMARK_ADIPOGENESIS", 
"HALLMARK_ADIPOGENESIS", "HALLMARK_ADIPOGENESIS", "HALLMARK_HEME_METABOLISM", 
"HALLMARK_HEME_METABOLISM", "HALLMARK_HEME_METABOLISM"), gene_symbol = c("ABCA1", 
"ABCB8", "ACAA2", "ATP6V0A1", "BACH1", "BCAM"), entrez_gene = c(19L, 
11194L, 10449L, 535L, 571L, 4059L), ensembl_gene = c("ENSG00000165029", 
"ENSG00000197150", "ENSG00000167315", "ENSG00000033627", "ENSG00000156273", 
"ENSG00000187244"), human_gene_symbol = c("ABCA1", "ABCB8", "ACAA2", 
"ATP6V0A1", "BACH1", "BCAM")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), Biocarta = structure(list(gs_name = c("BIOCARTA_41BB_PATHWAY", 
"BIOCARTA_41BB_PATHWAY", "BIOCARTA_41BB_PATHWAY", "BIOCARTA_MHC_PATHWAY", 
"BIOCARTA_MHC_PATHWAY", "BIOCARTA_MHC_PATHWAY"), gene_symbol = c("ATF2", 
"CHUK", "IFNG", "PSMB9", "TAP1", "TAP1"), entrez_gene = c(1386L, 
1147L, 3458L, 5698L, 6890L, 6890L), ensembl_gene = c("ENSG00000115966", 
"ENSG00000213341", "ENSG00000111537", "ENSG00000243958", "ENSG00000168394", 
"ENSG00000206297"), human_gene_symbol = c("ATF2", "CHUK", "IFNG", 
"PSMB9", "TAP1", "TAP1")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))

> dput(all.deg[1:20,1:3])
structure(c(16.0169585624867, 14.3983080662428, 12.7844219145156, 
12.6674945373237, 13.8584047354367, 11.4701287213135, 11.2965288742659, 
11.9366292116147, 11.6048424871367, 10.6321876611007, 12.0689683323484, 
13.3409329445103, 10.5908838705824, 10.3534159325297, 10.7370348393483, 
10.8034504695594, 10.605206547087, 14.0621273664398, 10.4142092863359, 
10.8479496362099, 13.563719599839, 13.6166993468069, 12.9748157402651, 
12.7386065050292, 12.2201616898331, 11.8622984167001, 11.3725306988381, 
12.0707221230543, 12.1529189589039, 11.771799960131, 12.4387833200825, 
10.5620628312927, 10.7220040110937, 11.4503728229401, 10.4291531060469, 
10.3223034959225, 10.6262530060521, 11.3421878022593, 10.7911951987965, 
11.3880258197358, 11.3657998135948, 11.8253392160132, 12.1132082166185, 
11.5123143882139, 10.2967924742924, 13.4048729003784, 10.9648102451279, 
11.0711515438459, 12.0463551417785, 11.6531157089154, 11.6855154709822, 
10.2771475949368, 13.0402535629381, 12.5487733174171, 10.7300483912034, 
10.6824422624191, 10.7561499037779, 6.92034083055899, 11.3463803827439, 
10.5950591061763), dim = c(20L, 3L), dimnames = list(c("FTL", 
"CTSD", "HLA.A", "HLA.B", "CD74", "APP", "AHNAK", "CD63", "HSPB1", 
"ATP1A1", "PIGR", "C3", "ITGA3", "KRT18", "CANX", "HSPA8", "RPS19", 
"APOE", "LDHA", "PDZK1IP1"), c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01")))
```

Example expected output:

`Hallmark_ADIPOGENESIS`

```
structure(c(13.3409329445103, 14.0621273664398, 9.62350834450491, 
9.17335315622538, 10.5620628312927, 11.3421878022593, 10.3455414476918, 
10.2037816886873, 10.2771475949368, 6.92034083055899, 10.0005629273966, 
9.51524435132771), dim = 4:3, dimnames = list(c("C3", "APOE", 
"GPX4", "ECH1"), c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01"
)))
```

Comment: I think you should also give an example of `all.deg` data.

Comment: Your example data does not include overlaps between the gene symbols in `lst` and `all.deg`.

Answer (score 0):

```
all.deg <- 
  all.deg |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  rownames_to_column("gene_symbol")

lapply(lst,
       inner_join,
       all.deg) |> 
  lapply(\(x) split(x, x$gs_name))
```